# Java Inheritance classes with main method

Tags: java

I have 2 objects defined

In Object-1, When I reference the child object it invokes the child method m1() whereas in Object-2 when I reference the child method m1() it references the Parent object..

In both the cases I assume parent object will hold a child type object at runtime...

Object-1

```
    package pkgB;

    class Parent{
        static int i = 10;
        void m1(){
            System.out.println("In Parent = " + i);
        }

        static void m1(String s){
            System.out.println(s +i );
        }
    }

    public class Child extends Parent{
        static int i = 20;
        void m1(){
            System.out.println("In child" + Child.i);
        }
        public static void main(String[] args){
            Parent p = new Child();
            p.m1();

        }
    }
```

Object-2

```
package pkgB;



class Drink{
    public static void m1(){
        System.out.println("Im Drink method");
    }

}

class Coffee extends Drink{
    public static void m1(){
        System.out.println("Im Coffee method");
    }

}

public class test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Drink d = new Coffee();
        d.m1();

    }
}
```

Output Dobject-1:

```
In child20
```

Output Dobject-2:

```
Im Drink method
```

Comment: You cann not override static methods. And beside of that, you should NOT call static Methods on an instance. (Your IDE should display a warning!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

static methods are called by their Type while instance methods are called based on the object type. **static methods are not overriddedn**.

When you say,

```
  Parent p = new Child();
  p.m1();
```

You are creating reference type of `Parent` but object type of `Child`. `m1()` is instance method so it is overridden and the `Child` method is called because object is of type `Child`

But when you say,

```
  Drink d = new Coffee();
  d.m1();
```

here, `m1()` is `static` method which are bound to class type. So `d.m1()` will call the `static` method as `d` is of type `Drink`

Answer (score 1):

In your second example, the `m1()` methods are static methods. Your compiler should give you a warning when you execute `d.m1()`, something about referring to a static method in a non-static way.

Anyway, when you call `d.m1()` in the second example, you are really calling `Drink.m1()` since `d` is declared a `Drink`.

Answer (score 1):

Calling static method using reference variable means you are in state of Sin :)

static methods/variables are solely part of class and can not be overriden.